# Getting value of form textbox via Id on click of button

Tags: html, forms

I would like to click a button and have it go to a link that concatenates `mypage.html` with the value entered in the search box, but it doesn't seem to recognize it as a variable. What can I do to get the value of the text box?

```
<html>
<form role="search" action="mypage.html/'#searchterm'">

          <input type="text"  placeholder="Search" id="searchterm">

        <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set the form method="get" the value of search term will automatically get concatenated into the url as searchtem='whatever'.

If you want to redirect the page somewhere else, you will want to do that with JS. Make a function that processes the form and redirect the URL based on the value of the field.

Comment: @sMatthewDarnell  sounds reasonable but I don't really know Javascrapt. Can you post as an answer?

Comment: I posted an answer using some jQuery. It's a pretty basic function, hopefully this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form element to this:

```
<form role="search" id="myForm" action="mypage.html">
```

The javascript (this is jQuery) would be something like this:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Get the search term
    var searchTerm = $('#searchterm').val();

    // Append the search term to the root URL
    var url = "mypage.html/" + searchTerm;

    // Redirect the page to the new URL
    window.location.href = url;

    // Prevents the default behavior of the form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would like to achieve this, you can send it directly using PHP, or you can send it using javascript and AJAX to a PHP page. As you can see in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) small tutorial you can send the value of the entered input. AJAX will avoid the page from being refreshed while you search the data, so it will look better. It all depends on what you would like to achieve.

Please take into account that the value of the input cannot be sent on the ¨action¨ property of the form.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone who submitted answers, I actually figured this one out.

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<button onclick="go()">Click me</button>
<script>
function go(value)
{

window.open("mypage.html/" + document.getElementById('myInput').value)

}
</script>

</html>
```